# A problem with an Exact ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $$P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$$ be an exact equation, where P,Q are of the form :$$P(x,y)=x \cdot u(\frac{y}{x})$$ and $$Q(x,y)=y\cdot v(\frac{y}{x})$$
Given that $$u(t),v(t)$$ are differentiable with a continuous derivative, show that the general solution of the equation is $$xP(x,y)+yQ(x,y)=c$$

My approach:
Given that the equation is exact, then $$\frac{dP}{dy}=\frac{dQ}{dx}$$ we can then apply the chain rule in order to get: 
$$\frac{dP}{dy}=u_y(\frac{y}{x})$$ $$\frac{dQ}{dx}=\frac{-y^2}{x^2}u_y(\frac{y}{x})$$ and thus we can receive the following equality: $$x^2 \cdot u_y(\frac{y}{x})+y^2 \cdot v_x(\frac{y}{x})=0$$ Now I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Comment: Hi, use `\cdot` for $\cdot$ instead of $*$

Comment: What did you mean by: Given that the equation is exact, then $$\frac{dP}{dy}=\frac{dQ}{dx}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take into account $u$ and $v$ are single variable functions, so their derivatives are not partial derivatives allowing you to write the condition as 
$$u'(y/x)=-(y/x)^2 v'(y/x)$$
The general solution is given by $F(x,y)=c$ with $F_x=P$ and $F_y=Q$, integration by parts yields
$$F(x,y)=\int Q(x,y) \ dx=\int yv\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \ dy=\frac{y^2}{2} v\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) -\int \frac{y^2}{2x}v'\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \ dy $$
$$F(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2} v\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) -\frac{x}{2}\int \frac{y^2}{x^2}v'\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \ dy =\frac{y^2}{2} v\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) +\frac{x}{2}\int u'\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \ dy $$
And finally
$$F(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2} v\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) +\frac{x^2}{2}u\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) =\frac{xP(x,y)+yQ(x,y)}{2}$$
So the general solution is $xP(x,y)+yQ(x,y)=c$.